# vb net: How to handle a Gecko.DOM.GeckoInputElement click event

Tags: vb.net, gecko

Is there a way to handle Gecko.DOM.GeckoInputElement click event? 
I have a submit button in a  tag and I'd like to rise an event when I click it with the mouse. The website is open in a Gecko Browser.

I'm useing xulrunner-29.0b2.en-US.win32 and GeckoFx-Windows-29.0-0.1

My code is:

```
Friend WithEvents inputElement As Gecko.DOM.GeckoInputElement

Private Sub inputElement_click() Handles inputElement.Click

    MsgBox("a")
End Sub
```

but obviously "inputElement.Click" doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to add a DomClick Handler to the main control.

C#

```
browser.DomClick += click;
```

Then inside the handler look for your button and responded appropriately.

C#

```
click( object sender, DomEventArgs e )    
{

            if ( sender == null ) return;    
            if ( e == null ) return;    
            if ( e.Target == null ) return;    

            var element = e.Target.CastToGeckoElement();

            GeckoHtmlElement clicked = element as GeckoHtmlElement;    
            if ( clicked == null ) return;

            if ( clicked.TagName.ToLowerInvariant() == "input" && clicked.GetAttribute("type").ToLowerInvariant() == "submit" )

            {    
                e.Handled = true;

                MessageBox.Show("a");
        }
```